# Bootstrap full width sidebar with background color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have layout like
[this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvXCL.jpg)

The problem? How to make full-width purple background on part of left?
This is [my code](http://codepen.io/ricooktavianaw/pen/GZmqPR)

**HTML:**

```
<section id="screens-eight" class="clearfix">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 screens-eight-left">
                <div class="screens-eight-bg"></div>
                <p>
                    Ut Enim ad minim veniam quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris. Nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**CSS:**

```
#screens-eight {
    background: blue; 
    padding-bottom: 180px;
}
.screens-eight-left {
    background: #835fa8; 
    position: relative; 
    z-index: 0; padding-bottom: 
    80px; padding-top: 80px;
}

@media(min-width: 992px) {
    .screens-eight-left .screens-eight-bg {
    background: #835fa8; 
    left: 0; position: 
    absolute; top: 0; 
    width: 50%; 
    z-index: -1;}
}
```

Comment: do you want the background to be as wide as the whole page, or just reach to the left hand side?

Comment: @TimOgilvy I want just reach to the left hand side for example you can see an image in my answer

Comment: When selecting an answer that works, be careful to resize the window, solutions using only one media query may break when you change the grid size.

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution in my local machine. just follow below steps.

**HTML**

```
<section id="screens-eight" class="clearfix">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 screens-eight-left">
                    <p>
                        Ut Enim ad minim veniam quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris. Nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

**CSS**

```
    #screens-eight {background: blue; padding-bottom: 180px;}
.screens-eight-left {position: relative; z-index: 0; padding-bottom: 80px; padding-top: 80px;}

@media(min-width: 992px) {
    .screens-eight-left .screens-eight-bg {background: #835fa8; left: 0; position: absolute; top: 0; width: 50%; z-index: -1;}
}
```

** Now make 1 Image In Photoshop**

step 1:- create new image with height of 1PX and width of 3000PX
step 2:- fill 50% of left part with color code #835fa8. so you got left 50% of part with this color #835fa8 and right 50% part Blank (transparent).
step 3:- now save image as png format.

now call that png image in this ID="screens-eight"

so you have to add css

```
#screens-eight {
    background-image: url(line.png);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat-y: repeat;
}
```

so now your updated css will be as below

```
#screens-eight {background: blue;
    background-image: url(line.png);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat-y: repeat;
    padding-bottom: 180px;
}
.screens-eight-left {position: relative; z-index: 0; padding-bottom: 80px; padding-top: 80px;}

@media(min-width: 992px) {
    .screens-eight-left .screens-eight-bg {background: #835fa8; left: 0; position: absolute; top: 0; width: 50%; z-index: -1;}
}
```

I also uploaded that image which i create so you can get the idea. [image]

Answer (score 1):

You are using the bootstrap `.container` class, which restricts to a particular [grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container) using media queries.

If you want to reach the side of the screen, you will either have to use `.container-fluid` and then work inside that, or break your purple box out of the container using some kind of css or javascript magic.

You can nest and chase containers, but I can't promise it won't break anything.  Have a play with this: (taken from your code-pen).  You would then need to use percentages or spaces to move your lorem ipsum to where you want it.  ([Here is a codepen of the same code](http://codepen.io/TimOgilvy/pen/GZmjqZ))

```
<section id="screens-eight" class="clearfix">
  <div class="container-fluid">
     <h4>wide part of doc:</h4>
       <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-6 screens-eight-left">
           <div class="screens-eight-bg"></div>
             <p>
                  Ut Enim ad minim veniam quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris. Nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
             </p>
           </div>
        </div>
      <div class="container">
        <h4>Sneaky narrow part of doc 1, a container within the wide container. May break something.</h4>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="container">
     <h4>Narrow part of doc 2.</h4>
   </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

change class `container` to `fluid-container`

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-fluid

Answer (score 0):

here, try this code

```
<section id="screens-eight" class="clearfix">

<div class="cover">

            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 screens-eight-left">
                        <div class="screens-eight-bg"></div>
                        <p>
                            Ut Enim ad minim veniam quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris. Nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            </div>


        </section>






.cover
{background: #835fa8; 
    float:left;


    width:100%;
    }


#screens-eight { padding-bottom: 180px; position:relative;}
.screens-eight-left {position: relative; z-index: 0; padding-bottom: 80px; padding-top: 80px;}
```